# Typed property with index type can not be assigned value

Tags: typescript

I have an interface defined as:

```
export interface IGenericChannelSuggestion {
  emailText?: string;
  emailHtml?: string;
  sms?: string;
  [other: string]: string;
}
```

With the intent of allowing any property name (aka, the "other" key) but giving suggestions for some common names which are commonly used. I then have a class:

```
class TypedTemplate<T = IDictionary, O = IGenericChannelSuggestion> { ... }
```

where `O` is the output type that the `generate()` method will return. By default it will fallback to the above `IGenericChannelSuggestion`. However, to my great surprise, when I start implementing putting the generic typings into `generate()` I run into this error while initializing the output:

[image]

This confused me as there are NO required properties on `IGenericChannelSuggestion`. I guess possibly TypeScript isn't yet sure the type is an Object type but I'm fairly certain I've done this before.

Now it gets even more odd when I added the following line -- just to test things out -- directly below:

[image]

Not sure what I'm running into here or for that matter what exactly CAN be assigned to type **O**.

Answer (score 3):

> This confused me as there are NO required properties on `IGenericChannelSuggestion`

A generic constraint implies a *minimum* set of properties, not a *maximum*. So it's legal for someone to construct your class with `O` set to a *subtype* of `IGenericChannelSuggestion` which has *required* properties in addition to the optional ones you defined. When that happens, `{}` will lack that required property and you'll have a broken program when someone observes the `{}` object expecting to find the mandatory property they defined in their `IGenericChannelSuggestion` subtype.

Comment: if it is indeed objecting to possibility O being set with required props, which on second read you seem to be suggesting, is there a way to enforce that O have only optional props. I guess maybe that would be Partial<O>.